# Got error ExceptionWrapper in Finder.php line 590 the directory "" does not exist when run artisan test

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

This problem occurs after I upgrade my Laravel from 8 to 9.
At first running single test function in a feature test was not a problem.
But then after I added a 2nd test function, when ever I tried to run "artisan test",
I got the following error

```
PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper 

  The "" directory does not exist.

  at vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:590
```

This error did not happen when I run any other artisan command.
Only when running "artisan test" and when I have multiple functions within a single feature test.

So what I have done so far:

- At first I thought I was missing a directory, but that was not the case.
- Than I tried to run "composer dump-autoload", the error is still persistence.
- Next tried to removing vendor directory and run "composer install", again error is still there.
- I also tried some solutions for other "stack overflow question", like checking .gitignore list, debug from the code. Not helping, probably due to different exception case?
- Someone mention run "composer update", I have tried it but this is not solution for my problem.
- For laravel.log (as pointed out by @UnderDog, *thanks for your comment*) here is the error stack.

`local.ERROR: The "" directory does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Exception\\DirectoryNotFoundException(code: 0): The \"\" directory does not exist. at .../vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:592) [stacktrace] .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(86): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Finder->in('') .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(63): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->getConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application)) .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository)) .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(242): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application)) .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(383): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)`

`...`

This was exception trigger when running "artisan optimize" as well as "artisan test" (with multiple tests in a single file.

Comment: Show the entire stack trace from your laravel.log

Comment: @UnderDog unfortunately there were nothing recorded in laravel.log related to this error

Comment: @UnderDog correction = there was exception log , I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this error originated from my poor choice of variable name inside .env .

I used a variable name `APP_BASE_PATH="public_html"` inside my .env file.
And boy that was a mistake that not only make `artisan test`, but also `artisan optimize` to be totally "disabled".

So after I change it to `PUBLIC_DIR="public_shtml"` my artisan command works again.

I learn my lesson not to use any variable name inside .env without checking it first if it's used by core or any libraries that I used.

So I guess `APP_BASE_PATH` is a reserved name in Laravel core ?

Comment: Can I give you another tip about `public_html`. Check k out this gist: https://gist.github.com/johanvanhelden/29096a9ff31eac9b039d36056919abbb#file-reconfigure-laravel-instructions-md it's the complete instructions to change `public` to `public_html`. Imho the variable inside .env shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @UnderDog thanks for your tip ... similar to what I did ... but your tip is much cleaner solution compare to mine ... any way it was my mistake to choose `APP_BASE_PATH`